# How to Create a Stripe Charge with a Destination Parameter Using .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

With Stripe, it is possible to forward a charge using a [destination parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/quickstart#process-payment).
This Stripe documentation includes examples for a few languages, but not C#/.NET.

The [Stripe API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=dotnet) does have an example for creating charges, and mentions the optional destination parameter as a Dictionary. What would this dictionary parameter look like?

**.NET API Reference for create charge:**

```
var options = new ChargeCreateOptions
{
    Amount = 2000,
    Currency = "usd",
    Description = "Charge for jenny.rosen@example.com",
    SourceId = "tok_visa" // obtained with Stripe.js,
};
var service = new ChargeService();
Charge charge = service.Create(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this :

```
var chargeOptions = new ChargeCreateOptions()
{
    Amount = 2000,
    Currency = "usd",
    SourceId = "tok_visa",
    Destination = new ChargeDestinationCreateOptions{
        Amount = 100,
        Account = "acct_1DjoxfIPiUij0fru"
    }
};

ChargeService chargeService = new ChargeService();
Charge charge = chargeService.Create(chargeOptions);
```

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/v22.7.0/src/Stripe.net/Services/Charges/ChargeCreateOptions.cs#L45-L49